# "User removed" notification

Tags: support, reputation

[image]

So this just came into my rep notifications. What is it about?

I am guessing that *"User was removed"* means that someone had once upvoted a question (because of the *5*) of mine and now that $+5$ rep is being undone because his account is no more (for whatever reason).

If that is the case, then I guess it makes sense and it is completely fine, but I wanted to make sure just in case it had to do with some (wrong) action *I* took. I am guessing the older users here know what this is, so is it my initial guess? Or is it something else?

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed (and other questions linked there.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks.

Comment: If your account is temporarily suspended, are your upvotes also forfeited? I lost reputation points today ostensibly because a user's account was closed.  But then I noticed the poster of a question I had recently answered has his account suspended for a week.

Comment: @RandomVariable I would assume so. You should get it back though.

Comment: @RandomVariable No, a suspension doesn't remove the suspended user's votes. (S)he just can't deal out more votes during the suspension.

Comment: @RandomVariable I think I know who you are talking about. I lost 130 rep for the same reason yesterday. Wonder what has he/she done.

Comment: @achillehui Then do you temporarily lose reputation if someone's account is temporarily suspended? I'm sure we're talking about the same person. Going over some of his or her recent posts, I can't find any obvious reason for suspension.

Comment: @RandomVariable maybe the post is deleted? You don't seem to be 10k+

Comment: @Sabyasachi What post may be deleted? I'm not over 10,000 rep, but the person who was suspended is.

Comment: @RandomVariable I don't think you lose reputation if someone's account is suspended. Otherwise, I will lose much more rep. The user who get suspended is one of the few users here who keep on asking interesting questions and I have answered quite a few of them.

Comment: @achillehui Then why did you lose 130 rep points?

Comment: @RandomVariable It is caused by the remover of another user. The user get removed and the user get suspended seems to know each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation is spot on and it has nothing to do with a mistake on your side.

Comment: okay thanks. good to know.